# Single RewriteRule to create a redirection with two conditions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found this rule which works fine with just one condition which is: `foobar` is in the string.

I need to change this to include a new condition to have two conditions (instead of one):

- `foobar` is in the string. This is already working.
- `meetball` is NOT in the string.

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)foobar(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try following, written as per your shown samples. Also you need to create groups `(.*)` since you are not using them while redirection. You could add `NC` flag of apache to enable ignorecase to the URI values.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(?!.*metaball).*foobar.*$ http://www.example.com/index.php [NC,L,R=301]
```

---

---

OR without negative lookahead try with usual condition check. Please make sure either you put above Rulesets OR following rulesets one at a time only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !metaball [NC]
RewriteRule foobar http://www.example.com/index.php [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [negative lookahead pattern](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```sh
RewriteRule ^(?!.*meetball).*foobar http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

`(?!.*meetball)` will fail the pattern match if `meatball` is found anywhere in URI. Also there is no need to use grouping hence `(...)` is removed in my answer.